# ActiveCell.Formula tipos de compativeis

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou Utilizando o VBA e me surgiu um impasse: Consigo usar uma variável que criei como parâmetro para preencher uma planilha?

Criei um Botão interativo e estou desenvolvendo um algoritmo que preenche a tabela, segue abaixo o código:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()      'Adicionar gasto
    Dim data As String, nome As String, centro_custo As String, empresa As String, nf As String
    Dim dat_pgto As String, recebimento As String
    Dim iLinha As Integer, cont_contab As Integer, valor As Integer

    iLinha = 3
    data = InputBox("Digite a data de solicitação:")
    MsgBox ("Data: " & data)

    Do
        iLinha = iLinha + 1
    Loop Until Cells(iLinha, 1).Value = ""
    ActiveCell.Formula(iLinha, A) = data
End Sub
```

Comment: pelo que vi você está querendo que ao final de uma faixa de valores ele coloque a data que você inseriu, correto? Também vejo o uso incorreto da propriedade .formula, penúltima linha. Recomendo que altere para Range("A" & iLinha) = data

Answer (score 1):

A resposta para sua pergunta "Consigo usar uma variável que criei como parâmetro para preencher uma planilha?" é sim.

Apenas seu código que está meio estranho, e não entendi muito bem o que você que fazer com ele.

Eu faria o final da seguinte forma:

```
     Do
            iLinha = iLinha + 1
     Loop Until Range(iLinha, 1).Value = ""
     Range(iLinha, A) = data
End Sub
```

Se especificar melhor o que você está tentando fazer, fica mais fácil. Qualquer coisa dá um toque :)

Answer (score 0):

ActiveCell.Formula só deve ser utilizado para colocar uma fórmula na célula, por exemplo:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(A1=B5;True;False)"
```

Lembrando que a fórmula deve ser sempre escrita em inglês independentemente da lingua de seu Office.